# disable jQuery Datepicker Icon doesn't work after PostBack

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui-datepicker

Does anyone know why I can not disable the datepicker image after a postback?

I'm taking a post in a PartialView.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    var cartaoCreditoContaBancaria = $('#ddlCartaoCreditoContaBancaria').val()
    if (cartaoCreditoContaBancaria.substring(0, 2) == "CC") {
        $("#txtCalendarioDataPagamento").datepicker("disable");
        $("#txtCalendarioDataRecebimento").datepicker("disable");
    }
    else {
        $("#txtCalendarioDataPagamento").datepicker("enable");
        $("#txtCalendarioDataRecebimento").datepicker("enable");
    }
  });
```

Comment: what does `console.log(cartaoCreditoContaBancaria)` give you?

Comment: Give some more info. How do the get and post actions look like? Which else is in the page? Do you get the data by AJAX or with "normal" GET/POST?